# find in mongoDB using pymongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I just started learning MongoDB. Am using pymongo. I want to use find function with some queries in it. But a getting error. Could you please help me.

[image: Here in this image am trying to get the document with particular id]

[image: my collection with 4 documents]

Also how to use other conditions like exist
[image: Example of exist]

Answer (score 0):

You need to import ObjectId in the beginning of your file:

```py
from bson import ObjectId
```

As for using strings and conditions, you need to use quotes. Also, boolean constants in Python are capitalized.

```py
db1.col1.find({"Ambiance": {"$exists": True}}
```